# RadioButtonList Choosing specific index

Tags: c#

I'm having trouble writing an if statement with the selected index of radio button list. Below is my code.

```
if(radioButtonList.SelectedValue = 1){

//code
}
```

I have a radiobutton list with 3 different indexes. How do I say something like if `selectedvalue = index [1]?`

Answer (score 1):

Try this

To set index:

```
radioButtonList.SelectedIndex=index;
```

To set value:

```
radioButtonList.SelectedValue=val;
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.radiobuttonlist%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

code to check selected index:

```
if(radioButtonList.SelectedIndex==index)
{
}
```

to check value

```
if(radioButtonList.SelectedValue==val)
{
}
```